# Can an employer in the U.S. establish an anti-bullying policy apart from formal legal harassment?

Tags: human-resources, bullying, harassment

My research has indicated that bullying in the U.S. is currently not prohibited *legally* under federal or any state law.  I haven't seen any info in my research about whether an employer could set up a conduct policy that is *more stringent* than the federal/state law.

Is there any reason an employer couldn't formally establish a definition of prohibited bullying that wasn't necessarily based on a legally protected class, and take action as a conduct issue when an employee engages in bullying under the definition?  For example, maybe a policy could state that prohibited bullying is any severe and/or pervasive behavior that a reasonable person would find insulting, threatening, or dominating.  (I'm sure there are holes in that example language, and would need to be vastly improved, and not interested in debating a specific policy here.  But just so you have an idea of the ballpark of what I'm talking about.  Some of the proposed state laws might have good language to look at for such a policy, although I haven't done that yet.)

Any knowledge of examples of such polices, and whether they have been successfully used/defended?

Comment: Most US companies already have anti-harassment policies that cover more than just the legally required protections, don't they? Bullying is bad for productivity. The company I work for says "...provide a work environment that is free of all forms of harassment...conduct that could be construed as harassment or sexual harassment is prohibited." While there is a statement about how the company is committed to following the law, the policy itself doesn't say it only applies when protected classes are the target of the harassment.

Comment: I'll just say that this is apparently not the policy at many companies, where they say that if it doesn't meet the legal definition, then it isn't actionable.  Same if you google it.

Comment: @EmilyBeth OK, but what is your question exactly? Such policies exist. Whether they're legally enforceable is a question for the courts. Trying to write an enforceable policy without a lawyer who specializes in the appropriate type of law is probably not a great idea, and definitely outside the scope of this site. Also, what do you mean by "actionable"? If it's not the law you can't go to court over it, but that doesn't mean the company can't take action that doesn't involve the courts to stop harassment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many states in the US have at-will employment.  In those, an employer can fire you at any time for almost any reason or no reason at all.  It is thus entirely within their power to state and promulgate a "no bullying" policy and then proceed to fire people for not adhering to it.

For those places where employment is more contractually protected, such a thing seems like it could easily be added to the employment contracts.  At that point, though, you're probably better off talking with a lawyer (which I am not).

Comment: Worth pointing out that many state actually do have anti-bullying laws.  However, they are primarily to protect our youth, not adults in the workplace.  Workplace anti-bullying policies typically are as simple as firing the workplace bully